# How to configure Oracle odbc connection on RHEL 5.?

Tags: unix, oracle11g, odbc, rhel, unixodbc

Can anyone please help me in configuring Oracle ODBC drivers on RHEL?
I have gone through some websites, but I am unable to sort it out.

Please give some elaborated answers, I am bit new to LINUX.

For now I have installed unixODBC and freeTDS on my linux machine.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the configuration that is not working? ...

Comment: I have configured TNSnames.ORA file located in /home/oracle/uo1/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin

Comment: please add that information incl. details to the question, so that the experts can take a look

Comment: actually I am trying to get the details of ORACLE database tables.
Oracle DB is on windows server and OBIEE is in Linux machine. 
I am trying to configure those DB details on linux machine so that I can work in OBIEE.

in TNSnames.ora i have entered below data.

EDWHCMB =
 (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =192.168.0.14)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = EDWHCMB)
    )
  )